# Is there have macro definition for Emulator on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there have a macro definition for Emulator, just like macro DEBUG defined by Microsft? Then I can write some codes which only working for Emulator easier.

If no, I need to define my custom macros for that. However one question haunts me: I have to define or undefined it in many *.cs files, if I want to run my codes on Emulator, I need to enable the macro in all the files either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using macro, but you can check if application is running on emulator this way :

```
if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == DeviceType.Emulator)
{
  //Put codes to run on emulator only here
}
```

`DeviceType` value can be `Device` or `Emulator` [[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.devicetype%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)].

To simplify further you can check `DeviceType` only once on application launching and have a global variable -f.e. `IsOnEmulator`- value set accordingly. Then you can simply check this way (assume that `IsOnEmulator` declared in App.xaml.cs) :

```
if (App.IsOnEmulator)
{
  //Put codes to run on emulator only here
}
```